# Azure AD App Proxy Cookie Integration using SAML with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cookies, azure-active-directory, saml

I am trying to integrate Azure AD App Proxy using SAML and Cookie based with our On-Promise application.

If I access the Azure AD App Proxy URL something like xxx.msappproxy.net , then Azure AD pre-authentication request made and ask for the login (username and password) then once logged in , it will successfully redirect to the internal URL (My Web Application Angular+NodeJS which hosted in on promise.)

Since I am using cookie based , I got the Cookies in browser as below

Name                                      Value
AzureAppProxyAccessCookie_XXXX_1.3        3|XXXXX
AzureAppProxyUserSessionCookie_XX_1.3     3|XXXXX
AzureAppProxyAnalyticCookie_XXX_1.3       3|XXXXX

I am not sure , how to submit the SAML request to get the token ID or Access token to get logged in user details.

Thanks Much Appreciate if any help.

Suresh

Comment: After going through (this complete documentation)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-on-premises-apps] make neccessary changes to your application and refine your question being more concrete - what do you do? At which step does it fail? What is the error message?

Comment: Once I access the Proxy URL , it redirected to AD login then it will return back to the my application with the Cookies mentioned above. Need to understand the Cookies information and how i submit the SAML request from NodeJS to get the token ID. I tried to achieve the below URL Sp Initiaed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-on-premises-apps